# Bootstrap 3 only works on "http://localhost:00000/" Not on the other pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I've implementet a bootstrap 3.0 theme in my MVC-aplication. But the theme only works on my `http://localhost:00000/`. If I type in the browser like:
    `http://localhost:00000/home/index`
or something like that the css and javascript doesn't work. But I get the html för it. All my code for like the: head, header, footer ect.. I have in my _Layout.cshtml file. I can't see the problem here why it's not working?

It ONLY works on my `http://localhost:00000/`.
NOT on the: `http://localhost:00000/home/index` (witch points to the exact same (controller/method/view as the fisrt one)

This is how my _layout.cshtml looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

<!--admintemat test-->

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="ThemeBucket">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
<link href="bs3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/jvector-map/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/clndr.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<!--header start-->
<header class="header fixed-top clearfix">
    <!--logo start-->
    <div class="brand">
        <a href="index.html" class="logo">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
        </a>
        <div class="sidebar-toggle-box">
            <div class="fa fa-bars"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--logo end-->
    <div class="nav notify-row" id="top_menu">
        <!--  notification goes here -->
    </div>
    <div class="top-nav clearfix">
        <!--search & user info goes here-->
    </div>
</header>

<!--sidebar start-->
<aside>
    <div id="sidebar" class="nav-collapse ">

        <!-- sidebar menu start-->
        <ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">
            <li>
                <a class="active" href="index.html">
                    <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                    <span>Dashboard</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub-menu">
                <a href="javascript:;">
                    <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>
                    <span>Layouts</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="sub">
                    <li><a href="boxed_page.html">Boxed Page</a></li>
                    <li><a href="horizontal_menu.html">Horizontal Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="language_switch.html">Language Switch Bar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="login.html">
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                    <span>Login Page</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</aside>
<!--sidebar end-->
<!-- sidebar menu end-->

<!--main content start-->
    <section id="main-content">
    <section class="wrapper">
        <!--main content goes here-->
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>

    </section>
</section>
<!--main content end-->
@*</div>*@

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

<!-- ADMINTEMAT TESTPlaced js at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<!--Core js-->
<script src="js/lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bs3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/accordion-menu/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.js"></script>
<script src="js/scrollTo/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/nicescroll/jquery.nicescroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flot-          chart/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="assets/jQuery-slimScroll-1.3.0/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
<script src="assets/skycons/skycons.js"></script>
<script src="assets/jquery.scrollTo/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/calendar/clndr.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min.js">     </script>
<script src="assets/calendar/moment-2.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/calendar/evnt.calendar.init.js"></script>
<script src="assets/jvector-map/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/jvector-map/jquery-jvectormap-us-lcc-en.js"></script>
<script src="assets/gauge/gauge.js"></script>
<script src="assets/easypiechart/jquery.easypiechart.js"></script>
<script src="assets/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js"></script>
<script src="assets/flot-chart/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="assets/flot-chart/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="assets/flot-chart/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>-->
<script src="assets/flot-chart/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
<script src="assets/flot-chart/jquery.flot.pie.resize.js"></script>
<script src="assets/flot-chart/jquery.flot.animator.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/dashboard.js"></script>
<!--common script init for all pages-->
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<!--ADMIN TEMAT TESTscript for this page-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The path to your assets is wrong. Most likely it's relative, and once you're in a sub folder, no longer points at the folder in the root. You either need to d ynamically change the relative path adding more `../` to it based on the level of nesting, or switch to using absolute paths.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that port (`00000`) is the one the NSA uses to read your email :)

Comment: Ok? I don't really know what you mean... My: http://localhost:00000/ and my: http://localhost:00000/Home/Index points to the same controller method and view.. So I still can't see the problem? Please help...

Comment: @Jason Sperske. Of course my port (00000) is somethis else ;)

Comment: Problem solved. Just a little bit of negligence by me... probably time to go to sleep.
I changed:
    <link href="css/bootstrap-reset.css" rel="stylesheet">

To: <link href="~/css/bootstrap-reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
On every css, js ect...
Thanks @Kevin B for pointing me inthe right direction :)

Comment: @patrick Of course all the cred of solving my problem goes to KevinB. And I really thank him for that. He solved it for me! I don't know why you even write the stuff that you just dit. If you think I was a little bit unclear in my answer to KevinB I think you can point it to me in a not so rude way

Comment: I don't think @user3228992 took credit for solving it, he just stated that it was in fact solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open your console, you'll see several 404 errors for each of your css assets and probably afew of your js assets. This is because you're using relative file paths. relative file paths look within the folder of the current file, therefore once you're viewing a file in  a sub folder, the relative paths no longer target the correct files. To fix it, use an absolute url.

```
/css/bootstrap-reset.css
```

the rest will need to be updated too.